# How to define complexity?

Tags: definition, physics, computer-science, biology, chemistry

Before Shannon's [1948](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematical_Theory_of_Communication) paper, most people hadn't realized that entropy, information, and their thermodynamics are closely related. I believe the concept of complexity today is also reducible between fields of science.

Computational complexity is a well established mathematical framework. [Complex network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_network) is a widely studied field in the physics of networks. [Complex Matter](https://www.quora.com/What-is-complex-matter) and [Complex Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_system) are also a common jargon in many fields of sciences.

I would like to learn about the generic definition of complexity, not just in the eyes of computational prescriptive. Is there such an effort to define complexity using communal terms? We do have the equivalence classes for computational complexity, but I haven't seen physicists using this kind of formalism as opposed to information theory and statistical physics.

My question boils down to whether there is a need or existing formalism to describe the complexity and how complex a system is?

Edit:

I found https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.2037 which is a nice introduction by Joseph Traub.

> Traub, Joseph F. "A brief history of information-based complexity."
> Essays on the Complexity of Continuous Problems", European
> Mathematical Society (2009): 61-71.

Edit 2:
[Leonard Susskind’s lecture](https://youtu.be/6OXdhV5BOcY): the notion of complexity as a metric defined as the minimal number of universal logic/quantum gates needed to apply on the vacuum state or on state A to go to state B. So the relative complexity between two entities is the minimal path in Hilbert space. Which is rephrasing what “reduction” is in a physicist’s language.   Since it’s associated with distances and volumes in phase space (space of possible configuration of the system) complexity induce some type of entropy.

Comment: Don't forget the theory of Kolmogorov's complexity ;-)

Comment: related to kolmogorov complexity is the minimum description length principle: https://homepages.cwi.nl/~pdg/ftp/mdlintro.pdf

Comment: May be, we can search for invariants using such complexity theory to realize some Knot  classifications

Comment: For a biological system using differential equations or some hybrid, if you can define how complexity connects to uncertainty/sensitivity, that would be helpful. At the moment, the standard approach consists entirely of numerical simulations. Each dynamical system contains some amount of information in the parameters and variables, which ultimately affects how sensitive the outputs are. Lots of sampling methods (and variance methods) have been developed to study this, but none strictly from an information theoric approach (as far as I know).

Comment: @Paichu would love to hear more. If you have a chance to compile it into an answer.

Comment: [Almost the same question on Physics SE.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296037/36360)

Comment: This might be interesting https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.13243. The authors have written a book as well ("What is a Complex System?") but it's not out yet

Answer (score 1):

> Is there such an effort to define complexity using communal terms? […]
> My question boils down to whether there is a need or existing formalism to describe the complexity and how complex a system is?

Being somewhere in the wide and diffuse field of complex-systems science, I am not aware of any efforts to define *complexity* nor does anybody seem to feel a need for it.
It’s more an “I know it when I see it” thing.
For example, the 90-page review paper *[The Structure and Function of Complex Networks](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S003614450342480)* hardly ever uses the word *complex* outside of the title, and not at all in a way that could serve as a definition.

The main reason for this is that no strict or surprising consequence arise from complexity in general.
You won’t have statements like: “If the system is complex, then *X.*” or “*X,* unless the system is complex.”
If anything, you might make similar statements with better defined properties that align with complexity (say *chaos,* though defining that is already a problem).
You may also sometimes find somebody using a very specific notion of complexity for specific objects, say time series, but that’s not what you are looking for.

Instead, the term *complexity* is more used to define a field of research.
And while some people may jokingly bicker that their research is about truly complex systems, the exact classification does not really matter as long as the research gains useful insights.